# changing header menu for the column from left of my alfresco

Tags: menu, header, alfresco, alfresco-share

I need to change the header of my alfresco menu to the left column removing the top, someone knows how to do it? which file should I edit?
I am using version 4.2.d

Comment: I'm not quite sure what bit you want to remove. Can you turn on surf-bug and use that to clarify what component(s) you want to hide, and/or post an annotated screenshot?

Comment: need to get the menu on the left, like this image: ![tela](http://www.casimages.com.br/i/131018072832751480.png.html)